# Total and Subtotal

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Question. List the product name, quantity delivered and the total and subtotal of sale price for all products that have been delivered in both PRODUCT and ORDERLINE tables. List in ascending product name order.

My Code:

```
SELECT
p.PRODNAME AS "PRODUCT NAME",
ol.QTYDELIVERED AS "QUANTITY DELIVERED",
ol.SALEPRICE AS "SALE PRICE" from ORDERLINE ol
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p ON
ol.PRODID = p.PRODID
ORDER BY p.PRODNAME ASC;
```

[My current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXJNc.png)

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJaGl.png)

Comment: Please post data as formatted text

Answer (score 0):

You could use this (use `CTE`)

```
with subtotal as
(
    SELECT p.PRODID, 
        p.PRODNAME AS "PRODUCT NAME",
        ol.QTYDELIVERED AS "QUANTITY DELIVERED",
        ol.SALEPRICE * ol.QTYDELIVERED AS "SALE PRICE" 
    from ORDERLINE ol
    INNER JOIN PRODUCT p 
    ON ol.PRODID = p.PRODID
    ORDER BY p.PRODNAME ASC
) 
select * 
from (select * from subtotal
      union all
      select PRODID, "PRODUCT NAME", sum("QUANTITY DELIVERED"), 
           sum("SALE PRICE")
      from subtotal
      group by PRODID, "PRODUCT NAME" 
     )
order by "PRODUCT NAME", PRODID, "QUANTITY DELIVERED";
```

You should include PRODID to calculate total in group by because PRODNAME may be not unique.